# vlookup looking in two columns

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a table on the left with Nodes and ID. Every pair of nodes correspond to a single ID.(N1 and N2 -> P1; N37 and N237 -> P238 ...)

On the right, i have a "matrix", which lists all my Nodes in column E, and all my ID's in row 1.

Inside the matrix, i want to write a value of 0.5 in the nodes that compose the same ID. The total sum of each ID must be one, because every ID has just two nodes.

[image]

I tried to use VLOOKUP to find the ID for each Node in column E, but it can be in column A or B, so i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use COUNTIFS starting in F2

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$E2,$C$2:$C$8,F$1)+COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$E2,$C$2:$C$8,F$1),0.5,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enter the below formula in cell `F2` and drag it right, then down to complete the range,

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX($A:$C,MATCH($E2,$A:$A,0),3),INDEX($A:$C,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0),3))=F$1,0.5,"")
```

[image]

Comment: in the example that i've posted, it fails for ID P34 and P35

Answer (score 0):

Use the index/match with combination with IF and OR. Enter the formula in F2 and drag across your range:

```
=IF(OR(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(F$1,$C:$C,0),0)=$E2,INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(F$1,$C:$C,0),0)=$E2),0.5,"")
```